# Has Kubuntu 15.10 been hacked?

Tags: firewall, kubuntu, ufw

Can someone tell me what this message means please?

```
[system] Rejected send message, 10 matched rules; 
type="method_return", sender=":1.19" 
(uid=0 pid=1183 comm="/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground")
interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" 
error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.9" 
(uid=0 pid=714 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon ")
Same message on ports 764 , 716 , 734 ,749 ?
```

Yesterday it was repeated 12 times - does this means that I got hacked? And I got a filed password check after one of these messages on the 25th which occurred 5 times and on 24th 4 times (the starting day of my log) and today the 28th for now twice. It seems I get this message whenever I log in.

I have installed GUFW firewall 5 months ago, and changed the profile from home to public today since I am living on a campus.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug, try to send them your system profile:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bind9/+bug/1488056

[axonic (guiltypixel-com) wrote on 2016-01-28](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bind9/+bug/1488056/comments/21):

> Also affecting Kubuntu 16.04 (kubuntu 15.10+dist-upgrade)

PS:

> And I got a filed password check after one of these messages on the 25th which occurred 5 times and on 24th 4 times

I think you should check the `/var/log/auth.log`

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I have reported this bug and as for the password my username was between curly brackets so it's my fault.